# Can I store the fetched data into store and use it e.g in another component?

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have made a simple app which gets data from a mock API and displays it on the UI.
My data is an array of objects.

I get the data like that:

```
export const getPlayerData = async (): Promise<IPlayerProps[]> => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://6360055fca0fe3c21aaacc04.mockapi.io/player`
  );

  return response.data;
}
```

And pass it to parent component like that:

```
const { data, status }: UseQueryResult<IPlayerProps[], Error> = useQuery<
    IPlayerProps[],
    Error,
    IPlayerProps[]
  >('players', getPlayerData);
```

So what I do after is just map the array of objects and display the data.

My question is that an employer asked me to use Redux and share the data between a parent and a child component, for example. Can I use Redux store to store the array of objects and use it in another page?

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using redux, you can create a reducer that will define what data should be stored on state. When various actions are dispatched, different data can be stored on state based on what you want changed with each action creator call. When you dispatch an action to fetch the data, you can also have a "succeeded" status action that can be used for the reducer to know to update state with the new data. You can then use selectors to grab that data from state from ANY child component. If you wrap the store around the entirety of an application, you can use it almost anywhere.

[Skip to section on "state, actions, and reducers"](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers)

```js
// actions file

import {createAction} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const FETCH_DATA_REQUESTED = 'FETCH_DATA_REQUESTED'
export const fetchDataRequested = createAction<any>(FETCH_DATA_REQUESTED);

export const FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED = 'FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED'
export const fetchDataSucceeded = createAction<any>(FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED);

// reducer file

import * as Actions from './actions';

export const initialState = {
  data: null,
  loading: false,
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  const {type, payload} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case Actions.FETCH_DATA_REQUESTED:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      }
    case Actions.FETCH_DATA_SUCCEEDED:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: payload.data,
        loading: false
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// selectors file (memoized data)

import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { initialState } from './reducer';

export const getPageState = (state) => state.somePageState || {};

export const getSomeData = createSelector(getPageState, (state) => state.data);
```

You can use "useDispatch()" from react-redux to dispatch the succeeded action after fetching your data. In another file you can use your selector to get the data

```js
// page a
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchDataSucceeded } from './actions';

const PageA = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch some data
    ...
    // after fetch
    dispatch(fetchDataSucceeded, data);
  }, [])

  return (...);
}

// page b
import { getSomeData } from './selectors';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const PageB = (props) => {
  const data = useSelector(getSomeData);

  return (...);
}
```

You will need to use base redux to set up a store and everything. I suggest creating the store at the top most level

For a modern slice approach, look here [scroll to create slice](https://blog.bitsrc.io/simplifying-redux-with-redux-toolkit-6236c28cdfcb)

Comment: I think you covered me completely, thanks a lot about that :)

Comment: This solution si not up to date. If you are using redux-toolkit the maintainers always recommend using slices not the regular redux vanilla reducers/actions https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice. And in this case, actionThunks https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Comment: @FerToasted do you have a more relevant link, in order to store the fetched data into the store and use it in another component?

Comment: Sure, you will probably have to use the `extraReducers` prop in the slice. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#the-extrareducers-builder-callback-notation. Accessing the data is the same with `useSelector(getSomeData)`.

Comment: @FerToasted Because I have no idea of Redux, is that something related of what we are talking about? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67897045/extrareducers-in-createslice-in-redux-toolkit

Comment: Yes, that's the recommended approach for a modern redux app and how to handle async requests and storing/requesting data with redux toolkit.

Comment: @FerToasted Could you take a look on this question? Am i so far from it as I think? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74270435/data-fetching-with-redux-rtk-watching-states

Comment: @kukri your solution is not far off from working with the modern slice methods from within redux. It's been a while since I've worked with redux so I forgot to mention it. Thanks you FerToasted for bringing it up!

Comment: @kukri this link should help. You can scroll down to the section on "createSlice" https://blog.bitsrc.io/simplifying-redux-with-redux-toolkit-6236c28cdfcb