# Data fetching with Redux RTK - watching states

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am very new to RTK, so I am trying to create a store and a slicer.

At first, at least I want to fetch some data from an API so when it start loading and after being succeed, I know the state of it.

Here I am creatinf the slicer:

```
const initialState: PlayerState = {
  players: [],
  status: 'idle'
};

export const getPlayers = createAsyncThunk('players/getPlayers', async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    'https://6360055fca0fe3c21aaacc04.mockapi.io/player'
  );
  return response.data;
});

const playerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'players',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addPlayer: (state, action: PayloadAction<IPlayerProps>) => {
      console.log('done');
      state.players.push(action.payload);
    }
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [getPlayers.pending]: (state, action) => {
      console.log('loading');
      state.status = 'loading';
    },
    [getPlayers.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      console.log('succeeded');
      state.status = 'succeeded';
      state.players = state.players.concat(action.payload);
    }
  }
});

export const { addPlayer } = playerSlice.actions;
export const selectPlayers = (state: RootState) => state.players.payload;
```

And here I am trying to connect it to the store:

```
//@ts-nocheck
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { addPlayer } from './playerSlice'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    players: addPlayer,
  },
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

So, after that I have a page with a button, so when I click it I try to dispatch something out of it with no luck unfortunately:

```
const NextPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
      <ButtonNext
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch(addPlayer);
        }}
        text="< Back"
      />
  );
};

export default NextPage;
```

Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

The are several issues in your code

First fix your `createAsyncThunk`

```
export const getPlayers = createAsyncThunk('players/getPlayers'
  async (_unusedArgs, _thunkApi) => {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/players')
    return response.json()
  }
)
```

Your slice should look like this, note the `builder` callbacks for the cases:

```
export const playerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "players",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addPlayer: (state, action) => {
      console.log("done");
      state.players.push(action.payload);
    }
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getPlayers.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
      state.players = action.payload;
      state.status = "idle";
    });
    builder.addCase(getPlayers.pending, (state, action) => {
      console.log("loading");
      state.status = "loading";
    });
  }
});

export default playerSlice.reducer;
```

Call it inside the anonymous fn

```
  <ButtonNext
    onClick={() => {
      dispatch(getPlayers()); // call with no arguments.
    }}
    text="< Back"
  />
```

And I also think that your root reducer in `store` is not right

```
import playerSlice from './playerSlice' // defaulted export

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    players: playerSlice,
  },
})
```

Please check this sandbox with working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-basic-players-w-pokemons-6wmjm0?file=/src/features/playerSlice.js:409-995

Comment: Yes I actually get an error in `console`: Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers.

Comment: and importing the default slice didn't fix it?